# subquery vs join which is better

Tags: join, subquery

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        table1
    WHERE 
        t2id in 
            ( SELECT id FROM table2
                WHERE t3id = 
                    (SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE id = '1') );


SELECT * 
    FROM 
        table1
        inner join table2
            on t1.t2id = t2.id
        inner join table3
            on t2.t3id = t3.id
    WHERE 
        t3.id = '1'
```

If I have the 2 query above which is better
what are pro/cons for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are doing different things so not directly comparable. The second one may give you multiple rows from table1 where the first one will not.

You may get the same row more than once in the second one if there are multiple rows in table2 or table3 that match ids.  The first query will not care because `IN` is not the same as a join.  Which one is faster is not relevant if only one of them is actually correct.

Comment: how can you that they wont return same data when *Both queries are logically equivalent, and they aim to fetch rows from table1 that have related data in table2 and table3 based on certain conditions.*

Comment: They are absolutely not logically equivalent!  One does a join, the other does IN.  IN implies DISTINCT.  Join will produce one tuple per row in the join condition.  Equivalency might be your aim, but that is not the case.  Put together some test data with multiple t2id and/or t3id and you will see.

Comment: i will try to test

Comment: @guradio If `table1.t2id` has 5 rows with the value `abc` in it and `table2.id` has 2 rows with value `abc`, then the first query will return only 5 rows but the second would return 10 rows. The `INNER JOIN` would cause a multiplicative result of rows. So the two queries are not perfectly logically equivalent.

Comment: @J.D. how about a CTE will it be same to the result of the sub queries?

Comment: @guradio a CTE can be logically the same as a subquery, yes, and pretty much the same in every other regard including performance.

Comment: @J.D. which would be better the sub query way or using CTE? performance wise

Comment: @guradio "*pretty much the same in every other regard including performance*" - There's no specific difference in performance when choosing one over the other.

Comment: appreciate all the answers.